# python config template performance improvements

Tags: python, python-3.x

im new to python and have created my first config generatign script. it reads a txt template looks for variables i have set then creates templates based on an excel csv i have with all my locations on.

it works, but im just looking for the most efficent way to do this as a learning curve for my next scripts.

```html
import csv
import os
with open('Data/ShowroomData.csv', 'rt') as Data:
    SR = csv.DictReader(Data, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in SR:
        # if you were to print just `row`, you would get a dictionary

        # set config file path
        folder  = 'Data/'
        filename = row['Host'].strip()
        path = folder + '/' + row['Location'].strip()
        R1file = path + '/STR-' + filename + '-RTR-01.txt'
        # check if path exists if not make path
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs (path)
        # Read in the config file
        R1 = None
        with open('Data/STR-RTR-01.txt', 'r') as R1Template, open(R1file, 'w') as configfile:
            R1 = R1Template.read()

            # Replace the target string
            R1 = R1.replace('$STR', row['Host'].strip())
            R1 = R1.replace('$IP', row['Subnet'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$DMVPN-DSL', row['DMVPN-DSL'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$DMVPN-4G', row['DMVPN-4G'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$BGPASNO', row['BGPAS'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$KCIP', row['KCIP'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$WRIP', row['WRIP'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$LOIP', row['Loopback'])              
            R1 = R1.replace('$DSL-USER', row['DSL-USER'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$DSL-PASS', row['DSL-PASS'])
            R1 = R1.replace('$Location', row['Location'].strip())
            R1 = R1.replace('$Date', row['InstallDate'])

            # check if the BT column is empty
            if row['BT'] == (''):
                for line in R1.split('\n'):
                    if '$BTSUB' not in line:
                        # Write file without BT static routes
                        configfile.write("{}\n".format(line))
            else:
                R1 = R1.replace('$BTSUB', row['BT'])
                # Write the file 
                configfile.write(R1)

print('Config templates are now complete!')
```

Comment: Not python specific: This is hard to read because it has too much going on in one function, well not even a function. You should break this apart into simpler units. At its worst, your code goes 'with, for, with, if, for, if' and that is not really acceptable.

Comment: could you show me an example of how i would separate this?

Comment: Just to reduce nesting and improve readability, you could separate the string replacement into another function. Alternatively, you could remove the first with-statement in favor of manually opening (and closing) the file which could also reduce nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code mostly looks fine. As for tips there are a couple:

1. Avoid using + to concatenate strings. Prefer string formatting 
   eg: `'/STR-{}-RTR-01.txt'.format(filename)`
   this has the advantage of being easier to read as well as avoiding excessive memory allocation and copying. As strings in python are immutable every use of + generates a new string instance.
2. When joining paths use `os.path.join`. This method keeps things more explicit, handles the separators and avoids string concatenation.

In the context of your script the above suggestion won't really make a big difference in execution time or memory usage, these can help large applications.

Finally instead of using "string.replace" to implement your templates have a look at Jinja2. Jinja 2 is a templating engine that can be easily configured for generating pretty much any kind of text based output (I've used it for code generation many times).

Comment: thanks! looking at Jinja now, how would a sample of the config look like with Jinja?

Comment: You don't provide the template in your example so I can't really duplicate it, however instead of $STR you would use {{ host }}. The nice thing about Jinja though is that you can do for loops, include conditions eg {% if BT %} Add BT details{% endif %}.

Comment: Written quickly off the top of my head. See GIST https://gist.github.com/timsavage/6554b93c2129216e6c66